# Adding options to select in HTML using Jquery and Materialize css Not working in laravel blade

Tags: jquery, json, materialize, laravel-blade

I am writing a Laravel project where I need populate select options using jquery but when I append the options are not added.
 Have googled related problems, but their solution did not work for me

**HTML CODE**

```
       <div class="input-field">
           <select name="subCategory" id="subcategory">
             <option value="" disabled selected>Select product sub-category</option> 
           </select>
         </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var jsonArray  = [
        {
            "id" : "1" ,
            "name" : "item1",
            "description" : "item 1 description"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2" ,
            "name" : "item2",
            "description" : "item 2 description"
        },
        {
            "id":"3" ,
            "name" : "item3",
            "description":"item 3 description"
        },{
            "id":"4" ,
            "name" : "item4",
            "description":"item 4 description"
        },
        {
            "id": "5" ,
            "name" : "item5",
            "description":"item 5 description"
        }

    ];



    $.each(jsonArray , (key , value)=> {
    console.log(value)
    $('#subcategory').append("<option>"+value.name+"</option>")  
    })

});

 </script>
```

Comment: check your browser console? does there any error ?

Comment: All the objects are logged on the console and there is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using materialize CSS framework make sure you initialize the select again, after appending new options.
 This worked for me

```
 $.each(jsonArray , (key , value)=>{
      var option = new Option(value.name  , value.id)
      $('#subcategory').append(option) 
    }) 
    $('select').formSelect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
function PopulateDropDown(jsonArray) {
    if (jsonArray  != null && jsonArray.length > 0) {
        $("#subcategory").removeAttr("disabled");
        $.each(jsonArray, function () {
            $("#subcategory").append($("<option></option>").val(this['id']).html(this['name']));
        });
    }
}
```